# can not reuse method android OOP

Tags: java, android, oop

In my application I can not reuse method I have declared in ArabicUtility class. My intension is to use Arabicutility class to arrange Arabic text. Therefore, what I want is passe string to the method I declared in Arabicutility class and do the conversion.

I think this is basically some problem of my knoweledge of OOP. so help me to correct this.

Here is the method I add to Arabicutility class

```
public void addTranslate(int rid, TextView txt1) {
        String textv = getResources().getString(rid);
        txt1.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(textv));
    //  Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/DroidNaskhBold.ttf");
    //  txt1.setTypeface(typeFace);

    }
```

I can not declare this method as static since getResources() is a non static.I had to extend from Activity since I use android methods.Originally It was not defined so.

this is how I try to use above method in other activity class.

```
arbic.addTranslate(R.string.butt18title1, txt1);
arbic.addTranslate(R.string.butt18desc1, txt2);
```

but When I run the programe it crashes when I go to above activities.

here is the log cat

```
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxx/com.xxxx.xxx.ShowMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at com.xxxx.xxx.ArabicUtilities.addTranslate(ArabicUtilities.java:252)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at com.xxxx.xxx.ShowMessageActivity.onCreate(ShowMessageActivity.java:184)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-29 10:02:32.561: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: See this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11449753/185722

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to declare `addTranslate` as static to get Resources in non Activity class you just need to pass Current Activity Context by using non activity class constructor or passing as in method as :

```
public void addTranslate(int rid, TextView txt1,Context context) {
        String textv = context.getResources().getString(rid);
        txt1.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(textv));

    }
```

Now you can call `addTranslate` from Activity class as:

```
arbic.addTranslate(R.string.butt18title1, txt1,Your_Current_Activity.this);
arbic.addTranslate(R.string.butt18desc1, txt2,Your_Current_Activity.this);
```

Comment: I mean do I have to declare the context all time when I reuse methods from other class?

Comment: @MenukaDevinda : because if you want to access Ui and from non Activity class you will need to use Context of Activity in which all Ui elements exist

Comment: ok but I have extends Arabicutility class from Activity. isnt it enough?

Comment: context.txt1.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(textv)); when add this line it shows error that txt1 can not be resolved to a field

Comment: @MenukaDevinda : because you are passing textView as parameter then no need to place context in front of  `txt1.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(textv)); `

Comment: perfect it works now. my final comment, I am new to Android, what area should I study to get these knoweledge , and actually I this is out of scope question. :). However, thanks again.

Comment: @MenukaDevinda : for these type of knowledge you will need to know  about Context class .

Answer (score 2):

The LogCat shows that Context in ArabicUtility is invalid. Try using the TextView's Context instead:

```
public void addTranslate(int rid, TextView txt1) {
    String textv = txt1.getContext().getResources().getString(rid);
    txt1.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(textv));
}
```

---

> I had to extend from Activity since I use android methods.Originally It was not defined so.
>
> this is how I try to use above method in other activity class.

If ArabicUtility is not the *active* Activity then you shouldn't extend Activity, you should try something like this:

```
public class ArabicUtility {
    private Context context;

    public ArabicUtility(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    ...
    public void addTranslate(int rid, TextView txt1) {
        String textv = context.getResources().getString(rid);
        txt1.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshapeSentence(textv));
    }
}
```

In your current Activity use:

```
arbic = new ArabicUtility(this);
arbic.addTranslate(R.string.butt18title1, txt1);
arbic.addTranslate(R.string.butt18desc1, txt2);
```

Comment: I updated my answer, you were right ArabicUtility should not extend Activity.

Comment: Thanks Sam!You gurs save lot of my time and I could leaern somthing from your valuable answers!