# Null Pointer Exception in Toast

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have not idea on what's going on. I have a timer and i need to show a toast message so i have to use runOnUiThread to make it happend. But when the code execution gets to Toast, it fail:

```
private void Print(String message)
    {
       final String CustomMessage = message;
        try{
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,CustomMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                            String b = e.getMessage();//Null Pointer Exception.
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception Error){}
    }
```

Here the watch.

[image]

What could be the cause? I've always done like that and nothing is null.

Update

Here one part of the LogCat

[image]

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace. If you do not understand what the stack trace is telling you, copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Can you post your logcat? It would have more details.

Comment: Are you throwing a custom exception that doesn't super a string message?

Comment: where is your print method defined ? is it in the MainActivity ?

Comment: @YAT yes, it's defined there.

Comment: @Misters Could it be the `Toast` which is `null`... try creating the `Toast` and then checking if its `null` before `show()`.

Comment: check ur msg srting is it null

Comment: @SecretSquirrel: `Toast` is not an object, it's a class.

Comment: @Nizam i was about to say the same.

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen see the image, CustomMessage is not null

Comment: can you post the stacktrace ? (e.printStackTrace())

Comment: @Nizam ok but surely `makeText` must return an `object` which has the `show()` method and I am suggesting that the `object` being created via the `makeText` is the `null reference`...

Comment: @Nizam http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html check under "The Basics"

Comment: Updated guys, Catlog image

Comment: @Misters check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449508/nullpointerexception-at-android-content-contextwrapper

Comment: @SecretSquirrel: Yup, `public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) ` surely returns an object of `Toast`, which is null here. And the problem is at `Context` parameter.

Comment: @Nizam so together we have answered the question to "What could be the cause?" :P

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use runOnUIThread , just do it like this :

```
private void Print(String message)
    {
       final String CustomMessage = message;

       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,CustomMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: Well, unless "I have a timer and..." from the OP is accurate.

Comment: the print method is private, in order to call it you have to be in the UI thread , so why using runOnUiThread ?

Comment: nop, still not working. Print method is declare in MainActivity. I did exactly as you but with not lucky, still Null Pointer Exception

Comment: ok try to put directly the message parameter in the makeText method like this : Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

don't use a final String

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity.this` instance is seriously messed up at the point in time when you are trying to show this `Toast`. Possible causes include:

- You are calling `Print()` from an initializer, constructor, or otherwise before `super.onCreate()` is called on the activity instance
- You created an instance of `MainActivity` through a constructor, rather than via `startActivity()`

Comment: I changed MainActivity.this for getBaseContext(). The toast is wrapper by the runOnUiThread and worked as expected